# How can I find out what proportion of values fall outside range?

Tags: r

```
v <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

And I mention max=4,min=2

So, I want to know how many values fall outside this range.

I can do this `(v < 2 & v > 4)`

But not sure how to do the count...

After that I will simply create a percentage with respect to total number of values (here 6).

Comment: `sum(v < 2 & v > 4)` I suspect you want `sum(v < 2 | v > 4)`, though because you won't have any number that is both less than 2 and greater than 4.

Comment: Thanks. The second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
sum(v < 2 | v > 4) / length(v)
[1] 0.5
```

You want to use `|` instead of `&` because no number will be both less than 2 and greater than 4.

Answer (score 3):

You can create and sum a logical vector. `TRUE` elements count as 1 and `FALSE` as 0, so this will give you the number of elements matching a particular condition.

```
v <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

sum(v < 2 | v > 4)
```

The latter returns 3 because there are three values less than 2 or greater than 4. The comparisons are vectorized, so `v < 2` tests whether each element of `v` in turn is less than 2. The OR operator is given by `|` in R.

To get the proportion of values beyond the range, you can divide the sum by the length of the vector, or alternatively use `mean()`, since the mean is the sum divided by the length.

```
mean(v < 2 | v > 4)
```